# Python for-loop to find the best values for SVC (C and gamma)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svc

I have a data set X and labels y for training and scoring a sklearn.SVC model. The data is split into `X_train` and `X_test`. I run a `for-loop` to find the best possible value combination (i.e. best score) for two SVC parameters: `C` and `gamma`. I can print out the highest score, but how do I print the C and gamma values that were used for this particular score?

```
for C in np.arange(0.05, 2.05, 0.05):
    for gamma in np.arange(0.001, 0.101, 0.001):
        model = SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=gamma, C=C)
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        score = model.score(X_test, y_test)
        if score > best_score:
            best_score = score
print('Highest Accuracy Score: ', best_score)
```

Comment: You can use GridSearch for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it to:

```
   if score > best_score:
        best_score = score
        best_C = C
        best_gamma = gamma
```

Or create a tuple:

```
if score > best_score:
    best_score = score, C, gamma
```

Answer (score 1):

Store them?

```
best_C = None
best_gamma = None
for C in np.arange(0.05, 2.05, 0.05):
    for gamma in np.arange(0.001, 0.101, 0.001):
        model = SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=gamma, C=C)
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        score = model.score(X_test, y_test)
        if score > best_score:
            best_score = score
            best_C = C
            best_gamma = gamma
print('Highest Accuracy Score: ', best_score)  
print(best_C)
print(best_gamma)
```